# Exception when initializing react-native-twitter-signin

Tags: react-native, react-native-twitter-signin

Ive been stuck on this for about 3 days now. I followed the instructions exactly like the docs - [link here](https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin). I have Added the callback url and all the other solutions on the internet. This error is on Android but ios doesn't do anything when i click the button. Also shows no errors or warning when debugging. Im using the react-native-twitter-signin package. Please help.[c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl8pJ.png)

Comment: Please share your code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to Rahul Mishra above for providing his code. I made a   a mistake of calling `RNTwitterSignIn.init(Constants.TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET` inside an async function. This worked for android but for ios nothing happened. But after i changed my code with his this worked and made me realise my mistake. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Here is my full code for react-native-twitter-signin which is working on iOS and android both:
Top of the class I called below code:

```
const { RNTwitterSignIn } = NativeModules
const Constants = {
  //Dev Parse keys
  TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY: "************************",
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "********************************************************"
}
```

This is my view file button:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.twitterSignIn()}>
            <Image style={styles.socialBtn} source={require('../images/twitter.png')}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

I am calling twitterSignIn function here:

```
twitterSignIn = () => {
  const fcmSocialToken = this.state.tokenFcm;
  RNTwitterSignIn.init(Constants.TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
  RNTwitterSignIn.logIn()
    .then(loginData => {
      const { authToken, authTokenSecret } = loginData
      if (authToken && authTokenSecret) {
        // You can use this data here and move next

      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  )
}
```

For iOS you need to update info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>twitterkit-YCZNs*********</string>
                <string>fb**********</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.************</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Please let me know if any issue.

Comment: I have modified my code to look just like yours where a button calls that function. I got it to work on android but still  nothing happens when i click the button on ios.

Comment: apppreaciate that mate

Comment: heres the link to more detailed question https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin/issues/153